# Memory implications for many firebase realtime updates

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my iOS app, I have a listener attached to an endpoint of the firebase realtime database that listens to chat messages posted by users of my app. Within the space of an hour, there may be tens of thousands of messages posted to this endpoint. On my app, I only show one message per second max, and discard the others that come in whilst that one is showing.
I know that firebase creates a cache for data that comes in through a listener, so will it be caching thousands of messages that were never displayed in the iOS app? If so, how can I stop this?

---

Update in response to answer by Frank:

> Firebase only keeps the latest snapshot of every node that it ever receives from the server

The problem I have had is that I store and listen to chat messages at the database node `events/{eventId}/chat`. I listen like this:

```
let query = rtdb.child(withPath: "events/{eventId}/chat")
            .queryOrdered(byChildKey: "createdAt")

query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
   // callback here
})
```

What happened for me was that whenever this listener was invoked at the same node in the database, it would first return all the data it had ever received from that node, and then listen for updates from the database node. That makes sense from your answer, as it is returning the cache of the `events/{eventId}/chat` node.

I had to add this to the query to only return updates from the database and no cached data:

`.queryStarting(at: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000))`

Should it be doing this, even though I'm querying `.childAdded` events, rather than `.value` events? This does seem that there will be memory issues as it's storing the whole snapshot of that `events/{eventId}/chat` node, which can be pretty large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have a listener attached to a location, Firebase does its best to deliver all data written to that listener. If you don't want all of these updates, you shouldn't keep a listener attached to the location.

If you have a location that gets updates thousands of times per second, consider setting up a secondary location that just gets the digested version of that data. Then your regular clients can listen to that secondary location that has a more reasonable update frequency, and you'd only need a single listener to the high-speed updated location.

---

From the comments it seems you're asking whether the Firebase client keeps all old data that it ever received. This is not the case: the Firebase only keeps the latest snapshot of every node that it ever receives from the server. It *does* keep a queue of local writes that were made on this client and that haven't been sent to the server yet, but that only significantly affects memory usage if a lot of writes happen between connections to the server.

Comment: I do show a digested version of the data to the user. I'm just wondering whether the thousands of pieces of data sent to my listener will cause my app to store every piece of data it receives in its memory cache?

Comment: The client only keeps the latest data it receives for each listener.

Comment: I will, I'm just still confused tbh. I know that if I don't set a startAt time, the listener will load all the local data when it first gets fired. I found this out the hard way! When you say "keeps the latest data it receives", how far back does "latest data" go? Is there a limit to the cache? Am I overwhelming the memory?

Comment: You seem to have a concrete memory usage problem, but are asking fairly abstract questions. For that reason all I can do is describe how the system works, but that's apparently not helping you. It's more likely that someone can help if you edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can focus on your code, and describe how the system works in context of that code.

Comment: It’s not an abstract question it’s really pretty simple: is every piece of data received from a listener cached on the client or not? And if so, for how long? This isn’t a coding problem. Firebase clearly has some kind of local cache but there’s not enough documentation on it. I’m trying to decide whether it’s going to overwhelm my memory in the long run.

Comment: I added some more explanation of how the client works.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my original question